# Optimal image scaling

Tags: php

I would like to ask for help in optimizing the image. I made a class where I call the function, working perfectly, just when I upload my profile picture I want to cut it into a square (800x800) and make it as optimal as possible from the center of the original picture. I don't want to use extra scripts, rather upload an optimally cropped image.

Imagecopyresampled proper parameter drop is the key :), I googled and watched videos but couldn't fix it properly or it either shifted the image or it wasn't in or distorted. I probably miscalculated the coordinates of the image.

```
function createthumb($name, $filename, $new_w, $new_h) {
        try{
            $system = explode(".", $name);
            $tipus = $system[count($system)-1];
            $tipus = strtolower($tipus);
            $vizjel_fajl = "assets/img/watermark.png";
            $vizjel_kep = imagecreatefrompng($vizjel_fajl);

            if (($tipus == 'jpg') || ($tipus == 'jpeg')){
                $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
            }
            if ($tipus == 'gif'){
                $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($name);
            }
            if ($tipus == 'png'){
                $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($name);
            }

            $old_x = imageSX($src_img);
            $old_y = imageSY($src_img);

            $vizjel_szelesseg = imagesx($vizjel_kep);
            $vizjel_magassag = imagesy($vizjel_kep);

            $szelesseg_szorzo = $old_x / $vizjel_szelesseg;
            $magassag_szorzo = $old_y / $vizjel_magassag;

            if (($szelesseg_szorzo) >= ($magassag_szorzo)){
                $aktual_szorzo = $magassag_szorzo;
            } else {
                $aktual_szorzo = $szelesseg_szorzo;
            }

            $vizjel_x = intval(($old_x - ($aktual_szorzo * $vizjel_szelesseg)) / 3);
            $vizjel_y = intval(($old_y - ($aktual_szorzo * $vizjel_magassag)) / 1);
            $vizjel_w = intval($aktual_szorzo * $vizjel_szelesseg);
            $vizjel_h = intval($aktual_szorzo * $vizjel_magassag);

            if($old_x > $old_y && $this->type != 'user'){
                $thumb_w = $new_w;
                $thumb_h = $old_y * ($new_h / $old_x);
            }
            if($old_x < $old_y && $this->type != 'user') {
                $thumb_w = $old_x * ($new_w / $old_y);
                $thumb_h = $new_h;
            }
            if($old_x == $old_y){
                $thumb_w = $new_w;
                $thumb_h = $new_h;
            }
            if($this->type == 'user'){
                $thumb_w = 800;
                $thumb_h = 800;
            }

            $dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);
            imagealphablending($dst_img, false);
            imagesavealpha($dst_img, true);
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
            imagefilledrectangle($dst_img, 0, 0, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $transparent);
            imagecopyresampled($src_img, $vizjel_kep, $vizjel_x, $vizjel_y, 0, 0, $vizjel_w, $vizjel_h, $vizjel_szelesseg, $vizjel_magassag);
            imagecopyresampled( $dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $old_x, $old_y );
            if ((preg_match( "/png/", $system[1])) || (preg_match("/gif/", $system[1]))){
                imagepng($dst_img, $filename, 1);
            }else{
                imagejpeg($dst_img, $filename);
            }
            imagedestroy($dst_img);
            if (!unlink($this->target_dir.$this->name)) {
                throw new userException('','Hiba a törlés során ->'. $this->name,451);
            }
        }
        catch (userException $e){
            $e->handleException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome LGB,
your function is not clear, I see some variables that not defined, please next time attach all of the codes.

this code returns exactly the center of the original image 800x800

```
<?php
//image path
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('Images/baby.jpg');

// find the size of image
$size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

//calculate X position
if(imagesx($im) < 800){$xPos = 0;}
else{$xPos = floor((imagesx($im) - 800) / 2);}
//calculate Y position
if(imagesy($im) < 800){$yPos = 0;}
else{$yPos = floor((imagesy($im) - 800) / 2);}

//set the crop image size
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => $xPos, 'y' => $yPos, 'width' => 800, 'height' => 800]);
if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");
       imagejpeg($im2);
    imagedestroy($im2);
} 
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

I'm guessing that your point is in this part:

```
//calculate X position
if(imagesx($im) < 800){$xPos = 0;}
else{$xPos = floor((imagesx($im) - 800) / 2);}
//calculate Y position
if(imagesy($im) < 800){$yPos = 0;}
else{$yPos = floor((imagesy($im) - 800) / 2);}
```